# Solve the irrational equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

I have tried to solve this equation but it grows, grows and grows and I do not come to anything clear, some idea or trick to solve it
Thank you

$$\frac{x+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{3}}}+\frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{3}}} =\sqrt{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$(\sqrt {a}+\sqrt {a+b})(\sqrt {a}-\sqrt {a+b})=-b $$

$$(\sqrt {a}-\sqrt {a-c})(\sqrt {a}+\sqrt {a-c})=c $$

Comment: is not the same ....The denominators are different

Comment: @Susana After multiplying by conjugates, you will get $\sqrt {3} $ in both denomnators.

Comment: Salahamam_ Fatima 21, thanks for help, *get to the roots of 3 you say, but from there on the problem is not how to reduce it, on the contrary seems to grow more*

Answer (score 1):

Multiply each fraction on the left with the conjugate of its denominator, so the first by $\frac {\sqrt x - \sqrt{x+\sqrt 3}}{\sqrt x - \sqrt{x+\sqrt 3}}$  There will be lots of simplification.

Comment: Already do that and grow

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If you have done this, please show where it got you and where you are stuck now.

Comment: Ross Millikan  thaks for help, "get to the roots of 3 you say, but from there on the problem is not how to reduce it, on the contrary seems to grow more "

Comment: I didn't say anything about the roots of $3$.  If you do what I suggested, the denominators in both fractions on the left become $\sqrt 3$.  Did you try it?  Multiplying by the conjugate should be a standard approach for problems like this.  You get terms like $x^{3/2}$ that need to be dealt with by squaring.  I think you get a cubic that has a single real rational root.  If you show what you have tried and where you are stuck, we can help much more.  -1

Comment: I will try there

Answer (score 0):

The domain gives $x\geq\sqrt3$.

We need to solve
$$(x+\sqrt3)\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt3}\right)+(x-\sqrt3)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+\sqrt3}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt3}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+\sqrt3}\right)$$ or
$$\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{x^2-3}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{3}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt3}+\sqrt{x-\sqrt3}\right)$$ or
$$\sqrt{x}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-3}\right)=\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{2x+2\sqrt{x^2-3}}$$ or
$$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2-3}}=\sqrt6.$$
Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-3}}.$

Hence, $f$ is an increasing function on $[\sqrt3,+\infty)$.

Thus, our equation has maximum one root.

But $2$ is a root, which says that it's an unique root.

Done!

Comment: Michael Rozenberg thanks for help, I really liked your approach and I understand it thanks for your time, even so you can get to the result in the conventional way - these problems always have some artifice - some idea, I have to solve it that way.